# How to reformat a micro SD card (not detected)

Tags: formatting, sd-card, hardware-detection

I want to reformat my sd card so I can use it again. I have no intents of recovering any data because I might have ruined it before I even started.

system: windows 7
sd card: ADATA 256GB 
So here is what happened:
1) my samsung s7 active gives error of unsupported sd card format.
2) put my sd card in an adapterto put it in my pc.
3) my pc directly recognises the sd card and gives a formating error.
4) searching for optimal formating settings. and start formating
5) after a few minutes I decided I want to cancel because it is taking me too long and the progress bar doesn't start filling.
6) my pc starts giving errors of sd card. I decide to start formating again but the start button is greyed out.
7) pull out sd card and put it back in but the sd card is not detected anymore 
8) in the mean time I have tried different tricks to let it show up again like: using diskmanagement, reinstalling drivers. And also used different computers to check if those would recognise the card.

I hope someone can help me out on this one.
greetings
Tony

Comment: Sounds like a dead card.

Comment: I'm afraid of it